# Rows to Columns in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

is there a way to transpose rows to columns in Azure Data Factory e.g.
I have an excel file with some vertical data in 2 column c1 & c2

```
c1 c2

A   B 
1   2
C   D
```

to

```
A  1  C
B  2  D
```

where A - 1 - C are the new columns and one row with the values B - 2 - D .

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot transformation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-pivot

Unpivot transformation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-unpivot